# If length is less than 0 alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have here a script for two text fields.

If the current length is 0 character... I want to alert that no characters left!

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
     <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="limit">10</span><br/>
    <input type="text" class="text_question_1"><br>
    <input type="text" class="text_question_1">
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("test!!");
    var combined_text_length = 0;
    var limit = 10;
    $("input.text_question_1").live('keyup', function (e){
      current_length = 0;


      $.each($("input.text_question_1"), function(index, value){
        current_length += value.value.length
        $(this).attr("#limit")
      })
      $("span#limit").html(limit - current_length)
    })
  })
  </script>
</html>
```

I tried to put...

```
if (limit < 0){
  alert("EXCEEDED!");
}
```

But not working.

Comment: check this fiddle out is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/JE2tW/

Answer (score 0):

`current_length += value.value.length` seems wrong. Use jQuery's own `val()` to retrieve the input field value as a string

Comment: It _seems_ wrong but only because of an unlucky variable naming.

Comment: But its working already i just have to state an alert if it exceeds

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (current_length > limit){
  alert("EXCEEDED!");
}
```

As you are never modifying the `limit` variable itself, it can not get lower than zero.

Note that an `alert` is not particularly user-friendly. Lookup the jQuery plugin "lightBox".

Also, it seems you are trying to use a `<input>`s where a `<textarea>` might be more appropriate.